# Can device file COMn be used for serial communication in java

Tags: java, windows, serial-communication

I'm looking for a way of doing serial communication with an usb modem without changing my java installation. It must on linux and windows.

On linux I can read and write to /dev/ttyUSB1 using bash. On windows I've tried making a FileInputStream+FileOutputStream to the device file named "COM3". I can make either a FileInputStream or a FileOutputStream. Not both.

Is there a way of using the file api for serial communication in java?

Answer (score 0):

RxTx library is the "standard" : http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page and runs well on all platforms. I think it is the only way to do serial IO with Java on Windows. The Linux system works because uses a transparent driver.

Even I found this file name convention for Windows: **\\.\COM3** (I never used this ...)